# Get error 404 on Postman with Springboot REST

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot

**PatientService**

```
@Path("/patientservice")
public interface PatientService {

    @Path("/patients")
    @GET
    List<Patient> getPatients();
}
```

**PatientServiceImpl**

```
@Service
public class PatientServiceImpl implements PatientService {

    Map<Long, Patient> patients = new HashMap<>();
    long currentId = 123;

    public PatientServiceImpl() {
        init();
    }

    void init() {
        Patient patient = new Patient();
        patient.setId(currentId);
        patient.setName("John");
        patients.put(patient.getId(), patient);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Patient> getPatients() {
        Collection<Patient> results = patients.values();
        List<Patient> response = new ArrayList<>(results);
        return response;
    }
}
```

I tried using hitting 
localhost:8080/services/patientservice/patients/ and localhost:8080/patientservice/patients/ 
as URLs but still getting 404 error screen. Can you please help me debug what might be wrong with the code?
The application runs properly with no errors.

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.bharath.restws</groupId>
    <artifactId>restws</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>restws</name>
    <description>Patient REST Services</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-spring-boot-starter-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-xc</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Comment: Please reformat your code and provide bit more information as to what you're trying to achieve and what is the exact problem.

In general the issue is evident but you should make this into a proper question.

Comment: Can you show your pom.xml or build.gradle file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need a Controller that will handle requests

```
@RestController
public class PatientController {

    @GetMapping("/patients")
    List<PatientModel> getPatients() {
        return Arrays.asList(
                new PatientModel("1", "john"),
                new PatientModel("2", "donald")
        );
    }

    static class PatientModel {
        private String id;
        private String name;

        // constructor, getters, setters
    }
}
```

So when you request patients with `curl http://localhost:8080/patients` it will return you a list `[{"id":"1","name":"john"},{"id":"2","name":"donald"}]`

and in this controller you may use any services from above that you have implemented

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do is a `REST controller` to catch your request and to forward to your service

First, add a `Qualifier` to your implementation of the `PatientService` interface so we can autowire it in the controller

```
@Service
@Qualifier("myImplementation")
public class PatientServiceImpl implements PatientService {
    // your code goes here
}
```

Then create your REST controller

```
@RestController
public class PatientController {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("myImplementation")
    PatientService patientService;

    @RequestMapping("/patients")
    public List<Patient> getPatients() {
        List<Patient> patients = patientServiceImpl.getPatients();
        return patients;
    }

}
```

Now your `/patients` endpoint is mapped onto the `getPatients()` method of the controller. This will in turn call the method on the service and return the result.

Using your implementation `PatientServiceImpl`, calling `http://localhost:8080/patients` returns

```
[{"id":123,"name":"John"}]
```